# How to create a SQL dump from the MySQL database files

Tags: mysql, xtrabackup

I am using Percona's xtrabackup to take backup of my online databases.
Is there a way to convert the backup database files into a SQL dump similar to a backup created using mysqldump ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the way Percona performs XtraBackup procedure includes running something like rsync against a running production server and then applies InnoDB crash recovery against a tmp folder (the backup directory) with the option to generate ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 that can be drop-in replacements for the ones in production](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3354/what-is-the-difference-between-xtrabackup-and-rsync/3356#3356). That data is just a backup.

If all your data is InnoDB, you are better off just [doing a mysqldump against production using the --single-transaction parameter. Even better, you can do parallel mysqldumps of databases or inidivdual tables again using --single-transaction parameter on each mysqldump process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it's taking a file level copy of `/var/lib/mysql` (or the Windows equivalent)?

If that's the case, restore the files somewhere and change the MySQL data directory to where you have restored `/var/lib/mysql` to, e.g. in `/etc/my.cnf` (or the Windows equivalent):

```
datadir=/tmp/restore/var/lib/mysql
```

Then restart MySQL and you'll be using your recovered databases which you can use `mysqldump` against.

If you're using InnoDB tables you may need to [read through this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html).